# What is the correct way to get the link url?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

We have a `Basic Page` content type with a link field (`field_link`). When we call the `mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables)` hook in a custom module we use `ksm($node->get('field_link')->first())` and it returns a `Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LinkItem`. We need to extract the URL from this fields and have found two ways to do it (see below). What is the correct way to get the URL from the field?

The reason for extracting the URL is that we need to wrap a set of custom fields with the link so we can have a HTML structure similar to below.

HTML structure:

```
<a href="/some/path" target="_blank">
  <img src="some/image/path">
  <span> Some title field </span>
</a>
```

**mymodule.module**

```
...
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $node_field_link = $node->get('field_link')->first();

  // Do we use this?
  $node_field_link_url = $node_field_link->getUrl()->getUri();

  // Or do we use?
  $node_field_link_url = $node_field_link->get('uri')->getValue();
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Url object from the link field with [LinkItemInterface::getUrl](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21link%21src%21LinkItemInterface.php/function/LinkItemInterface%3A%3AgetUrl/8.6.x) and build a new link, for example:

```
$variables['link_with_image'] => [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => [
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#uri' => $image_uri,
    '#width' => 60,
    '#height' => 40,
    '#alt' => $image_alt,
  ],
  '#url' => $node->field_link->first()->getUrl();
  '#attributes' => ['target' => '_blank'],
];
```

Normally you don't do this in preprocess and build such render arrays in a field formatter, see for example [Image Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_attributes) and [Linked Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field).

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to get a url especially when I'm using it in cases where I need to wrap custom html around it is to get the url object and then use the toString Method.

```
$node_field_link_url = $node_field_link->getUrl()->toString();
```

The getUrl() method of the LinkItem object returns a Url object. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x 
And Url objects have a toString method that returns the string representation of that url.

Comment: There was some discussion to avoid using toString() and instead using toRenderArray(). Just a suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a link to a discussion about that? I'm curious as to why.

Comment: Sorry, @matt! My bad, mistook the documentation for the [Link::toString()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

I always get stuck when I have to deal with Link fields, so let me answer this question for anyone who can help and for myself in the future:

The URL field is a `\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList` object.

PHP:

If you only have one value:

```
$mylink_url = $node->field_link->first()->getUrl()->toString();
// or 
$mylink_url = $node->field_link[0]->getUrl()->toString();

$mylink_title = $node->field_link->first()->title;
// or
$mylink_title = $node->field_link[0]->title;

// On ...->first() you get a \Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LinkItem
// On ...->getUrl() you get a \Drupal\Core\Url object.
```

Twig:

You can't use the `first` method, it will throw a `Twig\Sandbox\SecurityError` error.

```
My URL link: {{ node.field_link[0].url.toString() }}
My URL title: {{ node.field_link[0].title }}
```

If your field has more than one value, just use a `for` or `foreach`.