# How do I convert "entity:node/9 in a link?

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to get some values from a custom block I've created, and I am using the following code.

```
// Get the block
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('hightlight');

// Get the block content
$uuid = $block->getPlugin()->getDerivativeId();
$block_content = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('block_content', $uuid);

// Get the field value
$field = $block_content->get('field_link')->getValue()[0];
```

The problem is that the field contains *entity:node/9*. Is it possible to convert that value in a link?

This is the content of the field.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why not render the field? If you want to get the url to build your own link then use getUrl(), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267497/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-the-link-url

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't like a normal link field, I can't use the getUrl() function, I've added a screenshot of the dump of my variable

Comment: The properties you've just added to the question look like a normal link field and then you can apply the method getUrl() to compute the URL object.

Comment: When I use the getUrl() I got this error : `Error: Call to a member function getUrl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite

```
$value = $block_content->get('field_link')->getValue()[0];
```

to something like this:

```
$value = $block_content->get('field_link')->first()->getUrl()->toString();
```

See [What is the correct way to get the link url?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267497/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-the-link-url?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks it works !